# Group by date in mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have comments schema having createdAt field

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5acafcf834d81a1650a35b8c"),
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2018-04-09T05:41:12.228Z"),
    "author" : ObjectId("5ac8ba3582c2345af70d4658"),
    "comment" : "rgeregfedsagvdfsae",
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5acafcee34d81a1650a35b8b"),
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2018-04-09T05:41:02.992Z"),
    "author" : ObjectId("5ac8ba3582c2345af70d4658"),
    "comment" : "dsfsfdssfdsfdsf",
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5acb024134d81a1650a35b8d"),
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2018-04-10T06:03:45.625Z"),
    "author" : ObjectId("5ac8ba3582c2345af70d4658"),
    "comment" : "dsfdsafdafsdf",
}
```

I want to group by `createdAt`... And this should be my output

```
    [ { createdAt: '2018-04-09', numberOfComments: 2 },
      { createdAt: '2018-04-10', numberOfComments: 1 } ]
```

I have tried this...

```
const CommentsCount = await Comment.aggregate([
        {
          $project:
          {
            month: { $dateToString: { format: "%Y-%m-%d", date: "$createdAt" } },
          }
        },
        {
          $group: {
            _id: '$month'
          }
        }
      ])
```

gives `[ { _id: '2018-04-09' }, { _id: '2018-04-10' } ]`

Comment: the timezone section of the createdAt field is different amongst all the documents, i don't the result you desire is possible

Comment: @0.sh I think it is possible

Comment: see the updated question

Comment: You forgot to include the count aggregation in your `$group` i.e. `{
          $group: {
            _id: '$month', numberOfComments: { '$sum': 1 }
          }
        }`

Comment: @AshishChoudhary check the below answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `$addFields` operator

```
db.collection_name.aggregate([
    {
        $project:
        {
            month: { $dateToString: { format: "%Y-%m-%d", date: "$createdAt" } },
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: { createdAt: "$month"},
            numberOfComments: { $sum: 1 }
        }
    },

    {
        $addFields: {
            createdAt: "$_id.createdAt"
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: false
        }
    }
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
db.comment.aggregate(

    // Pipeline
    [
        // Stage 1
        {
            $project: {
                createdAt: {
                    $dateToString: {
                        format: "%Y-%m-%d",
                        date: "$createdAt"
                    }
                },
                author: 1,
                comment: 1

            }
        },

        // Stage 2
        {
            $group: {
                _id: {
                    createdAt: '$createdAt'
                },
                comments: {
                    $sum: 1
                }
            }
        },

        // Stage 3
        {
            $project: {
                createdAt: '$_id.createdAt',
                numberOfComments: '$comments',
                _id: 0
            }
        }

    ]


);
```